# Issue calculating Angstrom numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, while-loop, numbers

Angstrom number example: 153; `1**3 + 5**3 + 3**3 = 153`

```
puts "Enter a number: "
number = gets.chomp.to_i
initial_number = number
angstrom = 0
while (number % 10) != 0
    number = number % 10
    angstrom = angstrom + (number ** 3)
    number = number / 10
end

puts angstrom
puts initial_number

if angstrom == initial_number
    puts "YES ANGSTROM"
else
    puts "NO ANGSTROM"
end
```

EX: Input is 123

Entering while, we get 12 after the number % 10 statement.  But, after that, it doesn't go into while again; why is that? `12 % 10` shouldn't come out to `0`.

I added the `puts angstrom` and `puts initial_number` lines just to check what's going on with the numbers.

Comment: You're *completely* mutilating what you're looping with.  By the time you get  `number` back it's guaranteed to be 0, since whatever individual digit you pull out of the overall numeral is guaranteed to be less than 10.

Comment: In future, consider waiting awhile before selecting an answer. Quick selections can discourage other answers and short-circuit those still working on their answers. (Another answer was posted as I write.) There's no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before making a selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want something more along the lines of:

```
angstrom = 0
while number > 0
  digit = number % 10
  angstrom += digit ** 3
  number /= 10
end
```

to isolate each digit without destroying the number, and to avoid early termination from zeros contained internally in the input number.

### ADDENDUM

This is further improved (courtesy of Cary Swoveland) by using `divmod`:

```
angstrom = 0
while number > 0
  number, digit = number.divmod(10)
  angstrom += digit ** 3
end
```

Comment: Let's not forget that handy method [Fixnum#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-divmod). You could replace `digit = number % 10` with `number, digit = number.divmod(10)` and drop `number /= 10`. A reminder that if this is put in a method we need `angstrom` as the last line.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Excellent suggestion!  Yay Ruby!

Comment: Thanks, your method works the best, my while condition wasn't working with every angstrom number, because of the internal zeroes in the numbers.

Comment: pj, I hate seeing those addendums. Pretend you're writing an article for publication, as I believe you do from time-to-time. You go through several drafts, making changes that you think of or others have suggested. You don't keep what you had and say how you've changed it; you just change it. If you want to thank contributors you do that in a note somewhere (here it would be in a comment, as you have done). I'd like to see all answers here like that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland This is a case where opinions can differ.  I think there's value in showing a result based off Allen M's original version, and then a cleaner implementation based on your feedback.  Also, I like giving attributions where due (you're right, I'm an academic) and sometimes the comments are transient around here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way.

```
def angstromize(number)
  number.to_s.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,d| t+(d.to_i)**3 }
end

angstromize(153)
  #=> 153
```

Comment: Could also: `number.to_s.chars.map { |v| v.to_i**3 }.reduce(&:+)`

Comment: @tadman, your suggestion certainly reads better: "Convert `number` to a string, break the string into characters, convert the characters to integers, map each integer to its third power and then sum those values." I don't know which would be more efficient. Mine requires fewer passes through the array of characters, but Ruby may have tricks in C for common operations like `map(&:to_i)` and `reduce(:+)`.

Comment: It's all a matter of opinion, of course, but sometimes smaller, more obvious steps are better than fewer, more convoluted ones.

Comment: @tadman, true, in part because the more-smaller-steps approach may be easier to test and maintain (though what I have is pretty straightforward). I have no preference here.

Answer (score 0):

I hinted at this earlier in comments, but you're mutilating your `while` condition. You want to get a digit out from the numeral, but in the process, this line stomps it out:

```
number = number % 10
```

This guarantees that `number` will always be less than 10 and will always force your loop to bail early.  You'll also be calculating the entirely wrong thing.

The easiest solution is to create a new variable which represents the *digit* you extracted.

```
digit = number % 10
angstrom = angstrom + (digit ** 3)
```

Making this changes allows your test case of `153` to pass successfully.

Comment: Omg i can't believe i didn't notice it, i did something very similar earlier, but i did not save the digit into the same "number variable" .

Comment: I did something like:

Comment: angstrom = angstrom + ((number % 10) ** 3)